# Scanning with Java application 32 bit work on netbeans but not on RAD

Tags: maven, netbeans, 32bit-64bit, rad, twain

I have a Java application wriiten on a 64 machine system (windows7) using netBeans IDEA and complied using java 7 32 bit.
The application is running fine on a 32 bit machine and the scanner is working fine using `uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain`.
Now, I converted the project to a maven project and using RAD IDEA.
When I runnig the application on the same 32 bit machine I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.jtwain.ngetSourceManager()Luk/co/mmscomputing/device/twain/TwainSourceManager;
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.jtwain.ngetSourceManager()Luk/co/mmscomputing/device/twain/TwainSourceManager;
        at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.jtwain.ngetSourceManager(Native Method)
        at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.jtwain.access$100(jtwain.java:12)
        at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.jtwain$1.run(jtwain.java:347)
α⌠° 09, 2018 11:19:51 AM listener.ChooseFileActionListener scanFileActionPerformed
SEVERE: Cannot load Twain Source Manager.
uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.TwainIOException: Cannot load Twain Source Manager.
        at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.jtwain.getSourceManager(jtwain.java:127)
        at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.jtwain.acquire(jtwain.java:199)
        at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.TwainScanner.acquire(TwainScanner.java:62)
        at listener.ChooseFileActionListener.scanFileActionPerformed(ChooseFileActionListener.java:164)
        at listener.ChooseFileActionListener.actionPerformed(ChooseFileActionListener.java:72)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

I configure the build path to run JRE 7 32 bit, I even added a profile to the pom.xml:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>WIN_SWT</id>
    <activation>
      <os>
        <family>Windows</family>
        <arch>x86</arch>
      </os>
    </activation>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0):

UnsatisfiedLinkError means that native code (DLL under Windows) could not be loaded by the JVM, here the Twain driver.  You most likely need to redo the configuration in RAD that you did earlier under Netbeans (or an installer did for you) so the linking process can be successful.  This can also be caused by mixing 32-bit and 64-bit JVM's and drivers.